# SQL Server - Most efficient way to do multiple updates when WHERE cause is a unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, sqlperformance

Say I have 10-20k records to update in a SQL Server data, and I need to do something like the following:-

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Field1 = 95 WHERE MyTableID = 348923
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Field1 = 90 WHERE MyTableID = 348924
UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Field1 = 100 WHERE MyTableID = 348925
```

The MyTableID is a primary key, so guaranteed to be different every time. I am wondering what the most efficient way to run this is, when you start getting to 10k to 20k or even more UPDATE statements back to back, because I've read that every UPDATE is a seek of that table, which is already big.

I've considered and am aware of:-

- Cursor (currently looking preferable)
- Single list of UPDATE like above, and just deal with the slowness

Can anyone advise what the most efficient way is to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple query might be an efficient approach, since it can take advantage of the primary key index.

You could also try and use conditional expressions, like:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable 
SET Field1 = case MyTableID
    WHEN 348923 HEN 95
    WHEN 348924 THEN 90
    WHEN 348924 THEN 100
END
WHERE MyTableID IN (348923, 348924, 348925)
```

If the list of ids to update do come in range, the `WHERE` clause can be optimized in the following form, that would take advantage of the index:

```
WHERE MyTableID BETWEEN 348923 AND 348925
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I would recommend a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t
    SET Field1 = v.Field1
    FROM dbo.MyTable t JOIN
         (VALUES (95, 348923),
                 (90, 348924),
                 (100, 348925)
         ) v(Field1, MyTableId)
         ON v.MyTableId = t.MyTableId;
```

This should have essentially the same performance as using `CASE`.  I find it easier to manage.  And much simpler if you want to set multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a script template to handle the updates by creating a table variable as below

```
declare @your_tbl_name table
{
MyTableID int,
Field1 int
}
```

insert all your values into this table variable

```
insert into @your_tbl_name
select Field1,MyTableID from your [actualsource]
```

inner join this table variable with the actual table and update the values.

```
update t 
set t.Field1 = tbl.Field1
from dbo.MyTable t 
inner join @your_tbl_name tbl
on t.MyTableID = tbl.MyTableID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Gordon Linoff offered a great approach.
To determine if that's possible, do you need instant updates or can you batch them?

If you can batch them, consider how often the updates need to reflect on the master table.
You may have better luck adding all of the changes into a staging table, then running updates at a later time. This really depends on the performance you need, and what's eating your performance today. If you have a bunch of individual users all running updates concurrently, and each user needs to be able to update separate data instantly, then there are different approaches to consider. However, if you can handle updating these values only every so often, batch them! I receive a ton of updates from companies that sell to my company, and this is the route I've had to take for efficiency.

Here's how that batch would look if you can use a staging table.

```
--Creates a staging table
create table dbo.StageUpdates
    (
    ID int primary key
    , NewValue int
    )

--Adds values to update to staging table
insert into dbo.StageUpdates
VALUES
    (348923, 95)
    ,(348924, 90)
    ,(348925, 100)

--Update values
update dbo.MyTable
set Field1 = NewValue
from dbo.MyTable as mt
    inner join dbo.StageUpdates as su on mt.ID = su.ID
where su.NewValue <> mt.Field1 --Modify this if either value can be null.

--Clear updated values from stage
delete from dbo.StageUpdates
from dbo.StageUpdates as su
    inner join dbo.MyTable as mt on su.ID = mt.ID
where su.NewValue <> mt.Field1 --Modify this if either value can be null.
```